# Show product price element only in Post type pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've configured my theme to hide product elements like price, add to cart, category... And this affects all the websites.

I'm trying to get a PHP snippet to make the price element work only in `POST`-type pages.

What I have now:

```
// Active price: 
wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) );

//Regular price: 
wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );

//Sale price: 
wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
```